# Other expression for 'keep/maintain together'

Tags: synonyms

Other expression for 'keep/maintain together', in the context: a middle material that maintain the surrounding materials together.
'...while mineral bridges and organic matrix maintain the aragonite bricks together '
Thank you

Comment: You'll have to provide context and a sentence where you want the word to fit.

Answer (score 1):

> **glue**
>   something that binds together
>
> *enough social glue … to satisfy the human desire for community* — E. D. Hirsch, Jr.
>   — [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glue)